# Unable to map Image links using RestKit

Tags: xcode, json, image, restkit

I'm using RestKit and **not able to map the image links** from my JSON response correctly.

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2013-05-10T03:09:39Z",
    "feed": [{
        "headline": "Head text",
        "links": {
            "api": {
                "news": {
                    "href": "http://api.website.com/v1/91"
                },
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://api.website.com/v1/91"
                }
            },
            "web": {
                "href": "http://website.com/the/story"
            },
            "mobile": {
                "href": "http://m.website.com/wireless/story?storyId=9254113"
            }
        },
        "source": "Associated Press",
        "description": "Description text.",
        "images": [{
            "height": 324,
            "alt": "",
            "width": 576,
            "name": "Name text",
            "caption": "Caption text.",
            "url": "http://a.website.com/media/2013/0508.jpg"
        }],
```

Feed.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Links *links;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Images *images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Video *video;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *headline;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *source;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *published;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *premium;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
```

Feed.m

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"headline", @"headline",
         @"source", @"source",
         @"published", @"published",
         @"description", @"description",
         @"premium", @"premium",
         nil];
        [mapping hasOne:@"links" withMapping:[Links mapping]];
        [mapping hasOne:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];
        //[mapping hasMany:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];
        [mapping hasOne:@"video" withMapping:[Video mapping]];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}
```

Images.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *height;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *width;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *caption;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
```

Images.m

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"height", @"height",
         @"width", @"width",
         @"caption", @"caption",
         @"url", @"url",
         nil];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}
```

*Error: "W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:244 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'images'. No strategy for transforming from '__NSArrayM' to 'Images'"*

**Everything else works fine**, but images are not working because they are slightly different than all of the other data.

Really can't figure out the answer and **would be very appreciative to any help**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the property for `images` on`Feed`

```
property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
```

And use the `hasMany` relation

```
[mapping hasMany:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];
```

Comment: Didn't know about the hasMany relation. Cool.